# Java HashMap - Optimized way of appending a new value to a vector which is a value in a HashMap<String, Vector<String>>

Tags: java, hashmap

A similar way to appending new element to a vector like in C++ :-

```
myHashMap[myKey].push_back(newElement); //push newElement to the value vector directly
```

The only way i can think of in Java is to get the vector from hashmap. Append the new string to the vector and then set the key again with the new vector.

```
myValue = myHashMap.get(myKey);
/**Check if the key exists

**/
//If exists
myValue.add(newElement);
myHashmap.put(myKey, myValue);
```

Is the second approach as fast as the previous and if not is there any other approach? Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `myHashMap` in your C++ example code?  I want to know ... are you comparing apples and apples?

Comment: Its the same as it was in java. Map<String, Vector<String>>

Comment: In Java you should be using `ArrayList` rather than `Vector`.  The `Vector` class is legacy and has synchronization overheads that you should avoid if you can.

Comment: Thank you. Had a habit of using vectors coming from C++. Will give `ArrayList` a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to put back the vector back in the map as you are already modifying the vector when adding to it.

```
myHashMap[myKey].push_back(newElement);
```

is achieved by

```
myHashMap.get(myKey)
     .add(newElement);
```

(assuming `myHashMap.get(myKey)` does not return a *null*).

---

You can use `computeIfAbsent` in the Map interface to construct a vector object for a key processed for the first time. This is more elegant and does not require a *if* block.

```
myHashMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Vector<>())
            .add(newElement);
```

The function (`k -> new Vector<>()`) is only executed if the `myHashMap` does not have a mapping for the key `key`. The nice thing about this is it returns the vector value of `key` so that we can chain the `add` call on it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The second approach looks very clean. Didnt know chaining was possible here. One more question if you dont mind. Does get return a reference to the value or is direct modification possible only via chaining.

Comment: Java is always call/pass by *value*. But the value is the *reference* (to Vector) here. So, even with *get* you can achieve the same result.

Comment: Note that the second solution is only available with Java 8 and later.  But it is definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you care about performance in Java, use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`.  As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) says:

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, [`Vector`] was retrofitted to implement the `List` interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, `Vector` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`.

So, assuming we are using Java 8 (and `ArrayList`), there are two translations for the C++ code.

Version #1.  Works for Java 5+

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
...
ArrayList<String> list = myMap.get(myKey);
if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    myMap.put(myKey, list);
} 
list.add(newElement);
```

Version #2.  Works for Java 8+

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
...
myMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> ArrayList<>()).add(newElement);
```

Which will be faster?  You would need to test it to be sure, but I think that the second version should be a bit faster because it avoids the second hashmap lookup in the `put` call.

And 1 line of code is neater than 6 lines.  (YMMV for readability.  It depends on the person reading the code, and how familiar they are with Java 8+ language features and APIs.)

Comment: Thank you. In terms of performance both will suffice. I am using Java 10 so I will go with the second approach since it looks cleaner. I was confused because I didn't know that a pointer will be returned. This thread and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the same way in java.
`myHashMap.get(key).add(newValue)`
 Because in the hashmap the reference of list (or you can say it vector) is stored as value. So modifying the content of List will not influence the reference. You can  imagine this reference likes 64bits address of a vector in c++.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. Just found out about the pass-by-value and pass-by-reference confusion in java. Helped me understand about this problem.